# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Tags: swift, audio, time

I'm trying to set my sliders value to the sounds currentValue but then I get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'Double')
```

I am kind of new to Xcode and errors so I don't really know how to solve this problem but I tried to delete the string part but that did not work.

```
@IBAction func time(sender: UISlider) {

var timeValue:String = String(Int(sender.value)) sound!.currentTime = timeValue

}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Could you provide a little more information, and possibly format your question a little more clearly?

How did you define "sound", and "sound!.currentTime = timeValue" is the start of a new line, right?

Answer (score 2):

`timeValue` is a String and currentTime most likely is a NSTimeInterval. You can't assign string to NSTimeInterval. Use `Double(sender.value)` instead. Also, I would suggest that you do not combine so many operations on one line, especially if you are new to programming or Swift. If you get an error, you don't easily see if the problem was with conversion to String, to Int, if your `sound` variable was nil or what else is going on.